# Keyboard Events Not Triggering in Input Element and InputText Component on macOS

Tags: blazor, maui, keyboard-events, macos-ventura, maui-blazor

The keyboard events, such as @onkeydown, @onkeyup, and @onkeypress, are not triggering for the input element or InputText component in a MAUI Blazor app running on macOS. While these events work fine on Windows machines.

```
<input @onkeydown="KeydownHandler" @onkeypress="KeyPressHandler" @onkeyup="KeyUpHandler" @onfocus="FocusHandler"/>

@code {

    public string ComboFieldsDimensionsAll_SelectedItem;

    public void KeydownHandler()
    {
    }

    public void KeyPressHandler()
    {
    }

    public void KeyUpHandler()
    {
    }

    public void FocusHandler()
    {
    }
}
```

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Run the attached MAUI app.
2. Focus on the input element.
3. Type any alphanumeric key inside it.

**Public project repo **

https://github.com/Deepak-Ramakrisnan/MAUI-KeyBoard

**Expected Result:**
The keyboard events should trigger for every valid key press.

**Actual Result:**
None of the keyboard events are triggered for the key inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your sample on **Mac Catalyst** with `macOS Monterey 12.6` and it can **trigger** the keyboard events such as `@onkeydown`, `@onkeyup`, and `@onkeypress` as expected.

Unfortunately, it is not supported yet on `macOS Ventura`. We are working on upgrading our infrastructure fully to `macOS Ventura` as `Xcode 14.3` now requires it and has proven to be a challenge but we are making good progress on it. For more details, you can refer to [[META] Xcode 14.3 Support for Xamarin, .NET 6/7 and MAUI #17561](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/17561).

Additionally, I noticed that you raised a new issue: [Keyboard Events Not Triggering in Input Element and InputText Component on macOS](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14099) on Github. You can continue following up on that thread.